# Which method is suitable for manufacturing this small scale geometry?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, cnc

I want to have a channel manufactured in the dimensions shown in the picture. Which method is suitable for it. I think CNC can not achieve to work in such small scale. That rectangular prisms with 1.5mm width are part of the whole body. They are not attached to surface.[image]

Edit: I forgot to mention; this part is metal and will be used in heat transfer application.

Comment: Why do you think CNC is not capable of small scale?

Comment: I assume small workshops can not work such small scale, I can not get contact with high-tech manufacturers. But eventually it was just assumption. I would like to learn if it is possible.

Comment: Most CNC job shops should be able to hold tolerances finer than 0.1 mm without issue, not unheard of to go finer than 0.01 mm. You do not have surface finishes or tolerances listed, that would also affect method of manufacture.

Comment: You could consider metal 3d printing. It's easy to upload a stl file and get an instant quote at a few places like shapeways.

Comment: This totally doable on a standard cnc machine, depending on your tolerances. The only think slightly exotic is that you would need a .75mm or smaller endmill, but I just checked and they're commonly available. https://www.mcmaster.com/End-Mills/mill-diameter~0-7mm/

Comment: Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Just define your tolerances (higher tolerance = higher $$), then send it to a couple machine shops to get quotes. They will pick the most economical method, and can usually recommend someone if it is outside of their capabilities. If you need high tolerances they may quote you EDM instead of CNC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_discharge_machining